# Need a regex for alpha numeric lower case and . and _

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex for alphanumeric lowercase characters plus it can include these 2 characters: `.` and `_`.

The string must start and end with an alphanumeric lowercase character.

There can't be these character consecutive: `..` or `__` or `._.` or `_._`.

Examples:

- `helloworlderrr` ✅
- `hello_.errr` ✅
- `.hello` ❌
- `hello_` ❌
- `hel__lo` ❌

Comment: Do you know how to do it if you forget about "consecutive" requirement?

Comment: @PM77-1 I have no idea on ho to do it

Comment: Then you need to study regex basics first.  Pick-up a tutorial of your choice. for example, https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this regex:

```
^(?!.*(__|\.\.|_\._|\._\.))[a-z0-9][\w\.]+[a-z0-9]$
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/2fXWAz/2).

```
^                            Start of string
(?!.*(__|\.\.|_\._|\._\.))   Negative lookahead - do not match if contains __ /.. / _._ / ._.
[a-z0-9]                     Match only lowercase alphanumeric
[\w\.]+                      Match [a-zA-Z_] and dot
[a-z0-9]                     Match only lowercase alphanumeric
$                            End of string
```